# Simple Outlook boilerplate VBA with tokens

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm a very new to this and I'm trying to create VBA code that will replace tokens in my outlook meeting boilerplate but cannot get the code right.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I currently have:

```
Sub Kickoff()


Dim objreply As Outlook.MeetingItem
Dim strhtml As String
Dim strproject As String


Set myItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\ttupper\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\DAVA Kickoff.oft")
    myItem.Display
strproject = InputBox("Enter Application Name", "replace %appname%")

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to explain exactly what you want this program to return and what it currently returns, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have appname somewhere in the boilerplate you can replace like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kickoff()

Dim myItem As MailItem
Dim strproject As String

Set myItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\ttupper\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\DAVA Kickoff.oft")
myItem.Display

strproject = InputBox("Enter Application Name", "replace %appname%")
myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "appname", strproject)

End Sub
```